# Replace this.grid.getColumnModel() function in 4.2

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am using latest version EXTJS and want to replace all this.grid.getColumnModel() method used in a plugin is there any to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

### First Approach

You can just [override](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-override) the plugin's `getColumnModel` method.  Try something like this:

```
Ext.override('plugin.namespace', {
  getColumnModel: function(a, b, c) {
    // your override here
  }
});
```

Placement of this code is fairly crucial, so I would either create an overrides file or just stick it in your app.js file.

### Second Approach

The worst, but still optional, approach is to manually modify the plugin itself.  Like I said, you can still do it, but it's not an ideal solution.